# Custom Payment form with simplify commerce

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, payment-gateway

I am trying to create a simple form where a client can input an amount, an invoice number and an e-mail and proceed to pay with **simplify hosted payments** ( https://www.simplify.com/commerce/docs/tools/hosted-payments )

The modal payment method uses the details below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"

        src="https://www.simplify.com/commerce/simplify.pay.js"></script>

<button data-sc-key="YOUR_HOSTED_PAYMENTS_ENABLED_PUBLIC_KEY"

        data-name="Jasmine Green Tea"

        data-description="Smooth tea with a rich jasmine bouquet"

        data-reference="99999"

        data-amount="3000"

        data-color="#12B830">

        Buy Now

</button>
```

I can easily create a form where a customer can input the details I need, but how to pass them to the simplify.pay.js ?

From my understanding it uses a similar way as stripe does.

Comment: The documentation link you posted contains a detailed explanation and examples. What's the problem?

Comment: It does, but it doesn’t say anything about inputting the amount or anything else in a form.

Comment: What happened when you tried the examples?

Comment: It just loads the form to enter the card details with the amount and description pre-filled

Comment: You want the customer to input the amount they are going to be charged?

Comment: Yes, exactly. A simple form where they fill in the amount, invoice number and email

Comment: Adding custom form tutorial is here: https://www.simplify.com/commerce/docs/tutorial/index